# Multiple social plugins using a single Facebook App ID?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

[Social Plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) offered by Facebook generally need to have a Facebook App ID associated with them. When using multiple social plugins ( or custom Graph API calls/logic ) on the same page, is it customary to associate them all with the same Facebook app? Since `FB.init` needs to be used in these cases ( Facebook Docs say to only call this once per page ), and a single app ID must be passed to it, it would seem using multiple app IDs is not the way to go. I know it works to use a single app ID, but it just seems sloppy to use the app ID of a social reading plugin I've built on top of the Graph API to also moderate Facebook comments. Can anyone shed some light on this? I've puzzled until my puzzler was sore.